# Non parametric Independence test between 2 continuous variables

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric, independence

I have a collection of pairs of continuous values (x1,y1), (x2,y2), ..., (xn,yn).  I'd like to perform a test to see if they are independent.  I don't want to assume the relationship would be linear or anything in particular, e.g. I'd like to catch relationships like y=x^2, y=abs(x), ....

I realize I could e.g. subdivide X domain into intervals and effectively transform the x's into discrete/categorical values, but that has at least one problem -- the answer could be dependent on the size of the intervals.  I've seen recent (last few years) research papers like https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5031 which I could try to read, but I feel like I'm missing something -- this seems like it would be a very common problem and have a lot of textbook theory & tests behind it.  No?

Comment: Both the relationships you mention are still *functional*; what about relationships like the last three (i.e. the ones on the far right) in the bottom row [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Correlation_examples2.svg), where there can be two or more typical values of $y$ for a given $x$? Or are you just after cases where you can write something like $y=f(x)+e$

Comment: I didn't think about such relationships, good point.  For the current problem I think a functional relationship is all I could make use of.  (But I'm also  curious of what methods are used for the non-functional case too.)

Comment: I'd suggest you consider treating them as two different questions. There are approaches for the functional case that won't work for the other; it's a much harder problem because there's a much 'larger' set of ways to make two things generally related; indeed, slicing into a grid as you suggested in your question is one way it's done. There are some questions already on site relevant to each question (in particular the more general dependence version is likely to close as a duplicate; I'm unsure about the functional-relationship one).